# Multiple projects on same root folder

Tags: webstorm

I have a directory like this:

```
htdocs
 - shared
 - project 1
   - css
   - JS
 - project 2
   - css
   - JS
```

etc.

Now I want to create 2 projects, one with the folders `shared` and `project1` and one with the folders `shared` and `project2`.

The first project I can create with `htdocs` as a root folder, and exclude `project2` as source directory.

However, when I want to create a new project with `htdocs` as a root folder, WebStorm sees the already created project.

Is it possible to create the project structure like I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. But it involves additional manipulations.

The idea is simple -- store `.idea` folder (project settings .. and the clue/marker for IDE that this is a project) somewhere else:

1. Create new empty project somewhere else
2. Go to `Settings/Preferences | Directories`
3. Remove existing Content Root
4. Add new Content Root -- the folder(s) that you need.

   You can **A)** add both folders as separate content roots (e.g. `shared` and `project 1` as per your example) .. or **B)** add `htdocs` and then mark unwanted folders as excluded (so it's not indexed and not participating in code completion etc).

   I suggest using `A)` option in general -- less files to work with for IDE (in `B)` -- even though the folders are excluded, they are still processed by IDE and can participate in certain activities).
5. Repeat the same for your 2nd project (for `shared` and `project 2` folders)

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-343 -- this ticket is for PhpStorm but describes the actual idea.

---

Alternatively:

1. Create project in `project 1` folder (and not `htdocs` like you were planning originally)
2. Add additional Content Root -- add `shared` folder -- it will be listed as separate node in Project View.
3. Do the same for your 2nd project.

Comment: Excellent, thanks VERY much. I used your example 1,2,3 and 4 and then option A. I did not know about the concept of 'content roots', I would not have thought about that as being what it is. Thanks again.